# DDD - Does Many to many relationships mean two different aggregate roots?

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregate

I'm facing the following issue: I have a very simple aggregate root `Product`, and a product contains `Image` entities.

Right now in code this relationship is expressed as a Many to One relationship like this:

```
class Product:
    Image[] images;
```

Now it happens that I need to make that relationship a Many to Many relationship, and a single image can be used by multiple products. Vaughn Vernon in one of its rules for aggregates states to only reference aggregate roots by ID to avoid transactional collisions.

Does that mean that I should turn the Entity Image into an aggregate root and change the product class to hold an array of Image IDs to solve my problem? What would be the best solution?

Comment: To solve *what* problem?

Comment: @RobertHarvey the problem of converting a many to one relationship to a many to many.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Well, I don't think that changes your aggregate root.  You'll still refer to a `Product` by its ID.

Comment: Why is that a problem? Is there a use-case in your domain that requires a list of `Products` to be managed via an `Image`? I'm having trouble synthesizing such a requirement. Besides the fact that, to me, `Image` screams Value Object (making this problem moot), changing a domain model should be done with purpose - to accomplish a goal. Simply modifying your database schema doesn't *necessarily* mean your domain model should be changed. That's the whole idea of the abstraction right?